# Delete all zeros slices from 4d numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray, 4d

I pretend to remove slices from the third dimension of a 4d numpy array if it's contains only zeros.

I have a 4d numpy array of dimensions `[256,256,336,6]` and I need to delete the slices in the third dimension that only contains zeros. So the result would have a shape like this , e.g. `[256,256,300,6]` if 36 slices are fully zeros. I have tried multiple approaches including for loops, `np.delete` and `all()`, `any()` functions without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an afficionado with numpy, but does this do what you want?

I take the following small example matrix with 4 dimensions all full of 1s and then I set some slices to zero:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.ones((4,4,5,2))
```

The shape of `a` is:

```
>>> a.shape
(4, 4, 5, 2)
```

I will artificially set some of the slices in dimension 3 to zero:

```
a[:,:,0,:]=0
a[:,:,3,:]=0
```

I can find the indices of the slices with not all zeros by calculating sums (not very efficient, perhaps!)

```
indices = [i for i in range(a.shape[2]) if a[:,:,i,:].sum() != 0]
>>> indices
[1, 2, 4]
```

So, in your general case you could do this:

```
indices = [i for i in range(a.shape[2]) if a[:,:,i,:].sum() != 0]
a_new = a[:, :, indices, :].copy()
```

Then the shape of a_new is:

```
>>> anew.shape
(4, 4, 3, 2)
```

Comment: Looks like @norok2 's answer appeared before mine. Sorry!

Comment: This solves the problem, I just replace .sum() by .any() for a better efficiency

Comment: Most importantly this sports explicit looping, which is less efficient then a fully vectorized approach.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reduce on all axes but the one you are interested in.

An example using `np.any()` where there are all-zero subarrays along the axis `1` (at position `0` and `2`):

```py
import numpy as np


a=np.ones((2, 3, 2, 3))
a[:, 0, :, :] = a[:, 2, :, :] =0


mask = np.any(a, axis=(0, 2, 3))
new_a = a[:, mask, :, :]
print(new_a.shape)
# (2, 1, 2, 3)
print(new_a)
# [[[[1. 1. 1.]
#    [1. 1. 1.]]]
#
#
#  [[[1. 1. 1.]
#    [1. 1. 1.]]]]
```

The same code parametrized and refactored as a function:

```py
def remove_all_zeros(arr: np.ndarray, axis: int) -> np.ndarray:
    red_axes = tuple(i for i in range(arr.ndim) if i != axis)
    mask = np.any(arr, axis=red_axes)
    slicing = tuple(slice(None) if i != axis else mask for i in range(arr.ndim))
    return arr[slicing]


a = np.ones((2, 3, 2, 3))
a[:, 0, :, :] = a[:, 2, :, :] = 0
new_a = remove_all_zeros(a, 1)
print(new_a.shape)
# (2, 1, 2, 3)
print(new_a)
# [[[[1. 1. 1.]
#    [1. 1. 1.]]]
#
#
#  [[[1. 1. 1.]
#    [1. 1. 1.]]]]
```